# Where is sculpt vertex paint in 2.92?

Tags: sculpting, vertex-colors

I have seen YouTube videos featuring sculpt vertex paint but the buttons for it don't appear in my sculpt menu. Some people have said it's an experimental feature that needs to be activated in the Preferences window but it is not included in the options. Has it been removed from 2.92? Could someone please let me know?

Comment: Hello and welcome, not sure if it's still under development, but is not available anymore, it was for 2.90 Alpha

Comment: Hi @Emir, thanks for your reply. Wasted a long time looking for this today. It seemed such a useful feature and you can actually see the buttons in the 2.92 Sculpting demo videos on the Blender website. Has no one missed it or wanted it back?

Answer (score 0):

### Get an alpha version and Enable Develope Extras

Since somwhere around 2.9 version series appeared, some experimental features are hidden by default (they are not ready yet, we don't want a basic user to mess their file with them).

You can enable experimental fetures by enabling the Developer Extras checkbox in the Preferences.

[image]

Then the Experimental tab appears and you can choose the feature to enable.
Vertex color in sculpting is the first one.

[image]

You could probably find the features while 2.92 was in aplha or beta version, but nowadays that the version has become official, it was removed.

You are more likely to find them in old 2.92 alpha versions, current alpha versions, custom builds...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Carlo but the only options I get in my Experimental window are Debugging Undo Legacy and Cycles Debug. None of the rest is included.

Comment: @PhaedonZacharoudes Most of the experimental features are removed when an official release is shipped. You are more likely to find them in alpha versions, currently is available the 3.0.

Comment: thank you for clearing this up.